# rename multiple directories by adding one character

Tags: command-line, rename, mv

I have multiple folders named as follow:

```
Name1  
Name2  
...  
Name9  
Name10  
Name11  
...
```

I need to rename them using `mv` command into:

```
Name01  
Name02  
...  
Name09  
Name10  
Name11  
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be actually renaming only 1-9, so that simplifies things tremendously:

```
for f in `seq 0 9`
do
  mv Name${f} Name0${f}
done
```

If you start moving into triple digits, things get a bit more complicated, but not insurmountably so:

```
for f in `seq 0 95`
do
  g=`printf %03.f $f`
  mv Name${f} Name${g}
done
```

Comment: Actually i dont have all the folders of the sequence from 0-9. i might have Name2 and Name5 missing. But yet your solution is working fine. I only get a warning for the missing sequence folders.

Comment: for avoiding errors with non-existing directories, use e.g. `for f in name? ; do mv $f ${f//name/name0} ; done`

Comment: 10x @Fiximan! That's what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
rename -v 's/(\w)(\d)$/${1}0${2}/' Name[0-9]
```

Comment: Can't use rename. I need to change the name of folders not files.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MatrixStandard `rename` can operate all notwithstanding folders or files. If you have files which you do not like to rename you can use `Name[0-9]/` just for folders. Or more correct to make it through `find`: `find ./* -prune -type d -name 'Name[0-9]' -exec rename -v 's/(\w)(\d)$/${1}0${2}/' {} +`